# Proper usage of finally clause in try/catch block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to figure out the "best" way execute a (close) statement in my sql data access layer methods.

I was wondering which of the two ways is considered more correct (thanks):

**Option #1**

```
public void dbOperation( ... )
{
    try
    {
        _cmd.Open();        
        _cmd.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;       
    }
    finally
    {
        _cmd.Close()
    }   
}
```

**Option #2**

```
public void dbOperation( ... )
{
    try
    {
        _cmd.Open();        
        _cmd.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _cmd.Close()    
        throw ex;   
    }

    _cmd.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just a small comment: Don't use 'throw ex;' but 'throw;' to rethrow exceptions or the stacktrace will get lost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither is correct.  You shouldn't have a `catch` clause just to re-throw the exception again, clearing out its stack trace, and doing nothing productive, which is what your first option does.

You should *just* be closing in the finally:

```
try
{
    _cmd.Open();        
    _cmd.Execute();
}
finally
{
    _cmd.Close()
}
```

Your second snippet has the same problem with it, since you're improperly re-throwing the exception.

The best option would be to use a `using`, which is just a syntactic sugar for a try/finally without a catch:

```
using(var command = ...)
{
    command.Open();        
    command.Execute();
}
```

This has the added benefit of also ensuring that the scope of the command is exactly the same as when it's valid to use it.  A try/finally block requires the command to be a valid identifier after it has been disposed of.

Comment: I think `using` requires that the object be `IDisposable`.  Anything that has a `.Close()` *ought* to be disposable, but it's worth noting.

Comment: Great. I wasn't sure if omitting the catch was ok, just figured to keep my question simple and someone would point out everything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, if I re-throw in Option#2, dbOperation won't immediately return (thought throw implicitly returned)?

Comment: @SamusArin It'll immediately return, but it will replace the StackTrace member of the Exception with a wrong StackTrace, claiming that the error occurred at the point where you re-threw it instead of at the point where it actually happened. "[To keep the original stack trace information with the exception, use the throw statement without specifying the exception.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363.aspx)" (see example code at bottom). But as Servy said, there is no reason to re-throw at all.

Comment: @SamusArin I wasn't thinking, when I said it'll "replace StackTrace"; as Servy points out elsewhere, it will *clear* the StackTrace. By the time it's caught, "replacement" won't seem like a wildly wrong way to describe the difference, but it's the wrong way to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 is the only correct one of the two. In fact, you can get the equivalent of option #1 using less code:

```
try
{
    _cmd.Open();        
    _cmd.Execute();
}
finally
{
    _cmd.Close()
}
```

If an exception is thrown, there's no need to have a `catch` block to just re-throw it. If you want to do something in the `catch` block, such as logging the exception, be sure to do this:

```
try
{
    _cmd.Open();        
    _cmd.Execute();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logException(ex);
    throw;  //Just say throw, not throw ex, to preserve the original stack trace
}
finally
{
    _cmd.Close()
}
```

Comment: Your code is actually different from the OP's first example.  In the OP's example any exceptions have their stack traces blanked out.

Comment: @Servy: Not blanked, but restarted from the point of the cleanup code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes.  It's blanking it out, but not preventing it from being added to from then on.  The resulting exceptions trace won't be blank despite the fact that it is blanked out *at the point where it is rethrown*.

Answer (score -1):

Option #1. If you use option2 you won't execute cmd.close unless it throws an exception

Comment: Read the whole sample he provided. To handle the non-exception case, there's a Close at the end of the fucntion. You're wrong because you didn't even bother reading the OP. -1